# Find and replace word - case insensitive

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find and replace the "[num]" with my own word, but this does not work. If I remove "[" and "]" it works.

```
response = response.replace(/[num]/i, 'my text');
```

Comment: do you happen to have multiple num-s in the text that need to be replaced? Because, without the g flag it will only get the first occurence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
response = response.replace(/\[num\]/i, 'my text');
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JaHAW/29/)

**On a side note:**

If you want to replace text inside a square bracket then you can use this regex:

```
/\[[^\]]+\]/g
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape them as `[` and `]` are used in regex to specify a [character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set)

```
response = response.replace(/\[num\]/i, 'my text');
```

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets denote [] character classes.

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell
>   the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply
>   place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you
>   want to match an a or an e, use [ae]. You could use this in gr[ae]y to
>   match either gray or grey.

So the regex.replace in your code will replace, any occurence of "n or u or m" with "my text".

Answer (score 0):

If it is working, why do not you do removing "[" and "]",  can you provide so that i can figure out what you are really trying to so there?